# How to limit apt-listchanges mails to only security-updates

Tags: apt-listchanges

I am using [apt-listchanges](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/hardy/man1/apt-listchanges.1.html) to email me a summary of software on my servers.

I would like to limit these to security-updates and/or urgency=high changes.

So that I receive only mail from a server when there is a security-release or any other urgent release.

Is this possible with apt-listchanges? Or is there some other tool that could replace apt-listchanges, with this functionality built in?

My current Apt-listchanges is the default config as it comes with the installation; I did not edit anything. The file `/etc/apt/listchanges.conf` contains:

```
[apt]
frontend=pager
email_address=root
confirm=0
save_seen=/var/lib/apt/listchanges.db
which=news
```

Comment: How exactly did you configured apt-listchanges?

Comment: I have updated my question with the current configuration, @Braiam